# Automatic mercurial commit and push in build

Tags: build, mercurial

I have a build process which includes making changes to files and committing them to source control.
I am moving to use mercurial, and trying to figure out how to best do this.
The problem is that the process pulls from the main repository at the start and pushes back at the end (about 2 hours later). If someone makes changes to the repository during that time, push will fail because it is creating another head.
The obvious solution is to pull and merge before pushing, but in theory someone could still make changes even in this smaller time window.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, source control is for human output not build artifacts.  Consider have the build artifacts go into a dedicated artifact repository or separate repo.  If that's not workable maybe have the build merge `default` into a `ci` branch, do the build, and commit to `ci`.  Then you'll always have the commit from the build right after the code that went into it, and you can pull from the `ci` branch on your deploys.